# Duke do action on duplicate record

Tags: java, duke

I have created an application which is finding the duplicate records using the [DUKE](https://github.com/larsga/Duke)
The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException
{
     Configuration config =
                ConfigLoader
                    .load("<path>/src/main/recources/namebase.xml");
            Processor proc = new Processor(config);
            proc.addMatchListener(new PrintMatchListener(true, true, true, true, config.getProperties(),
                true));
            proc.deduplicate();

            proc.close();
}
```

It is working fine now may use case is to find the duplicate records and remove them. The PrintMatchListener is only able to print the records. So I have two questions:

- How to do action on duplicate record?
- The duplicate logic is saying that record 'A' is similar to 'B' and it is also saying the 'B' is similar to 'A'. I need only one way relation so that I can delete those records. Can anyone suggest any strategy.

Comment: from where you want to remove the duplicate records ? You can put your action where you are getting this statement ` 'A' is similar to 'B'`

Comment: I have a dataset I am finding the similar records. This code in just printing the information. How can I get the list of those similar records? So that I can delete them.